# USB Transmitter for RasPi, or GPIO solution Thru SPI

Tags: arduino, spi, nrf24l01

OK, so i am attempting to send and receive data from an arduino Uno to my ras pi via the NRF24 chips. i have been successfully able to communicate between the two HOWEVER, the pins i need for my 5" Touch Screen are utilized by the transmitter. Are there any good USB transmitter/Receivers i could use on my pi to free the pins for the screen up?

or is there any way to reallocate pin usage?

SCREEN: WaveShare 5" HDMI LCD V2 800x480 XPT2046

The Touchscreen in important for the final product that needs to be small and "self-sufficient". no keyboards/mice, etc... but small dongles would be fine.

[image: screen]

Comment: I did not check but if those are the UART pins, no.  If they are the I2C or SPI pins then you can use multiple devices on them at the same time providing they use different addresses (I2C), or the the chip select wire(s) (SPI), it is just a matter of making the physical attachment work.

Comment: according to the back of my screen it uses these pins:
MOSI, MISO, SCK, P6, CE1

the issues is it covers an entire block of pins to make the connection.

Comment: so then in theory... i could solder wires to the back of the pins i need for the transmitter and by use of the SPI/device tree protocols be able to use both things on the same pins....

Comment: I don't use the SPI port so I cannot say for sure (or I would write you an answer), I just know *in theory* it is usable with at least a couple of different devices simultaneously via the CE0/1 lines (aka GPIO 7 & 8).  You should edit that information into the question in case someone who does know in practice how to do this comes along.